# Spring rest controller returns XML if no mediatype set

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Controllers in my app by default return data in XML, but i expect JSON (I used https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ as reference)
But if i explicitly set the `MediaType`, for example `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })` data is returned in JSON format.
I have a lot stuff in pom.xml because i practicing with cloud stack. Can it cause some weird behavior with returning format?

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.microservices.practice</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservices-practice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>microservices-practice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.9.6</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=forex-service
server.port=8000

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Comment: No, the POM doesn't cause "weird" behavior with returning format. The fact that unspecified format *defaults* to XML is not weird either, it just happens to be the default. If you want a different default, but still support multiple format, use the `qs` qualifier to specify which format is preferred. The duplicate answer applies to Spring as well as Jersey.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but question is WHY in my case default format is XML, but in the spring tutorials it's JSON? What cause this behavior?

Comment: Probably because the tutorial didn't add support for XML at all, hence it cannot be the default. If your code supports multiple formats, it is *undefined* which format is the default. It may even arbitrarily change. To control the preferred format, *you* must explicitly specify which you want. That is the entire purpose of `qs`. If you don't explicitly specify a preferred format on the server, it means you don't care about format when client request is ambiguous. If client doesn't specify a preferred format, it means client doesn't care. If either cares, they must say so.